# How to solve the given equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve the following equation,

```
Solve[(c + 1)*(u - 1) + c*(k + 1)*(u - 1)*(u^(1/k) - 1) - 
   c*k*u*(u^(1/k) - 1) == 0, u]
```

c and k are constants. But I am not getting the solution. Instead of solve, I tried Reduce and NSolve. Is there any other method to solve this equation.

Comment: `Reduce[(c + 1)*(u - 1) + c*(k + 1)*(u - 1)*(u^(1/k) - 1) - 
   c*k*u*(u^(1/k) - 1) == 0]` derives a solution `u==1`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the command

```
Reduce[(c + 1)*(u - 1) + c*(k + 1)*(u - 1)*(u^(1/k) - 1) -     c*k*u*(u^(1/k) - 1) == 0]
```

> `(-k - u^(1 + 1/k) + u^(1/k) + k u^(1/k) != 0 &&  c == (-1 + u)/(-k - u^(1 + 1/k) + u^(1/k) + k u^(1/k))) || u == 1`

derives a solution `u==1`.
Second, one can symbolically solve  `c == (-1 + u)/(-k - u^(1 + 1/k) + u^(1/k) + k u^(1/k)))` for natural values `k==1`,`k==2`,`k==3`, and `k==4`. E.g.

```
k = 2; Solve[c == (-1 + u)/(-k - u^(1 + 1/k) + u^(1/k) + k u^(1/k)), u]
```

> `{{u -> (1 + 5 c^2 - (1 + c) Sqrt[1 - 2 c + 9 c^2])/(2 c^2)}, {u -> ( 1 + 5 c^2 + (1 + c) Sqrt[1 - 2 c + 9 c^2])/(2 c^2)}}`

Third, one can numerically solve that equation for some real values of `k` and `c`. E.g.

```
c = 1/E; k = Pi; Plot[c - (-1 + u)/(-k - u^(1 + 1/k) + u^(1/k) + k u^(1/k)), {u, 0, 50}]
```

suggests a possible root near the origin, so

```
FindRoot[c == (-1 + u)/(-k - u^(1 + 1/k) + u^(1/k) + k u^(1/k)), {u,0}]
```

> `{u->0.000785876}`